# Identifying relationships in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, identifying-relationship

Are nested classes a good way to model identifying relationships in Kotlin?

Requirements:

- an issue can not be without a serno
- a revocation can not be without an issue
- an affirmation can not be without a revocation

Looks quite verbose:

```kotlin
class Have {
    inner class Serno(val value: String) {
        override fun toString(): String = "serno: $value"
        fun nothing () = this@Have
        inner class Issue(val value: String) {
            override fun toString(): String = "issue: $value (${serno()})"
            fun serno () = this@Serno
            inner class Revocation(val value: String) {
                override fun toString(): String = "revocation: $value (${issue()})"
                fun issue () = this@Issue
                inner class Affirmation(val value: String) {
                    override fun toString(): String = "affirmation: $value (${revocation()})"
                    fun revocation () = this@Revocation
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

val serno: Have.Serno = Have().Serno("123")
val issue: Have.Serno.Issue = serno.Issue("SUP-1")
val revocation: Have.Serno.Issue.Revocation = issue.Revocation("2020")
val affirmation: Have.Serno.Issue.Revocation.Affirmation = revocation.Affirmation("2022")

println(serno)
println(issue)
println(revocation)
println(affirmation)

println(serno == affirmation.revocation().issue().serno())
```

Is there a simpler way to achieve the same?

Answer (score 2):

This would usually be achieved with simple non-null properties:

```kotlin
class Serno(val value: String) {
    override fun toString(): String = "serno: $value"
}

class Issue(val value: String, val serno: Serno) {
    override fun toString(): String = "issue: $value ($serno)"
}

class Revocation(val value: String, val issue: Issue) {
    override fun toString(): String = "revocation: $value ($issue)"
}

class Affirmation(val value: String, val revocation: Revocation) {
    override fun toString(): String = "affirmation: $value ($revocation)"
}

val serno = Serno("123")
val issue = Issue("SUP-1", serno)
val revocation = Revocation("2020", issue)
val affirmation = Affirmation("2022", revocation)
```

And if you're not strict on the `toString` format, you could even use the built-in `toString` of data classes, and simplify further:

```kotlin
data class Serno(val value: String)

data class Issue(val value: String, val serno: Serno)

data class Revocation(val value: String, val issue: Issue)

data class Affirmation(val value: String, val revocation: Revocation)
```